# how to access values in array of object in custom liquid shopify, this array of object is added in metafields of product

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-app, shopify-template

I have added an array of object in product metafields like below:

```
const response = await client.query({
        data: {
          "query": `mutation updateProductMetafields($input: ProductInput!) {
            productUpdate(input: $input) {
              product {
                id
                metafields(first: 3) {
                  edges {
                    node {
                      id
                      namespace
                      key
                      value
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
              userErrors {
                message
                field
              }
            }
          }`,
          "variables": {
            "input": {
              "metafields": [
                {
                  "namespace": "my_field",
                  "key": "faq",
                  "type": "json",
                  "value": "{\"objects\": [{\"question\": \"test 1\", \"answer\": \"yes I'm test 1\"}, {\"question\": \"test 2\", \"answer\": \"yes I'm test 2\"}] }"
                }
              ],
              "id": "gid://shopify/Product/435353534"
            }
          },
        }
        
      });
```

Now I want to access these in my custom liquid, I tried accessing it but nothing is shown

```
{% assign product_metafields = product.metafields.my_field.faq  -%}

{% for object in product_metafields.objects %}
  <p>Question: {{ object.question }}</p>
  <p>Answer: {{ object.answer }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Kindly tell me where the issue is.

Comment: You know you cannot update properties from the front-end right?